# Check proof for a statement of linear independence involving 5 matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B,C,D,E \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$

I'm asked to prove or disprove that if the set $A = \{EA,EB,EC,ED\}$ is linearly independent so the set $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is linearly independent.

I was having troubles with matrices algebra but this is my shot, I'm not sure I'm allowed to factorise $E$ but here's it:

The set $\{EA,EB,EC,ED\}$ is linearly independent if and only if:
$$\alpha\cdot EA + \beta\cdot EB + \gamma\cdot EC + \delta\cdot ED = 0$$
$$ \Rightarrow \alpha = \beta = \gamma = \delta = 0 $$

Thus, if we factor out $E$ out of the first equation we get that
$$E\cdot(\alpha\cdot A + \beta\cdot B + \gamma\cdot C + \delta\cdot D) = 0$$
We know that $A$ is linearly independent so $E \neq 0$, thus we get that:
$$ \alpha\cdot A + \beta\cdot B + \gamma\cdot C + \delta\cdot D = 0 $$
We also know that
$$\alpha = \beta = \gamma = \delta = 0$$

Thus, $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is linearly independent.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: What is $E$?...

Comment: You seem to have mixed up linear dependence with linear independence. Also, matrices dont just cancel like that. (if $AB=0$, and $A\neq 0$, it does not follow that $B=0$)

Comment: You were right I mixed up linear dependence with independence, and I also forgot to mention that $E \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$. What is the way to prove the required if my algebra is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct argument goes like this. **Assume**
$$
a A + b B + c C + d D = 0,
$$
with $a, b, c, d \in \Bbb{R}$.

**You have to prove that this implies $a = b = c = d = 0$.**

Multiply by $E$ on the left to get
$$
a E A + b  E B + c E C + d E D = 0.
$$
By assumption $EA, EB, EC, ED$ are linearly independent, so this implies $a = b = c = d = 0$, done.

Comment: Aren't you arguing the converse of what is being asked? It doesn't seem like your argument can be reversed, since $E$ isn't necessarily invertible.

Comment: @Adriano, isn't the question *if the set $\{EA,EB,EC,ED\}$ is linearly independent then the set $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is linearly independent*?

Comment: But if I assume $a A + b B + c C + d D = 0$, I'm assuming what's being asked to prove, don't I?

Comment: @Georgey, no, linear independence means ***if** a linear combination is zero, **then** all the coefficients are zero*.

Comment: @Adriano, the question has been edited. We were reacting to different questions.

Comment: In this case, what makes my proof fall? Matrices algebra?

Comment: @Georgey, your proof fails at two points. First, the logic is wrong, you are not trying to prove that the definition as I stated it is satisfied. (To prove linear independence, you have to prove the **if ... then** I stated.) Second, you simplify by $E$, but this can only be done if $E$ is invertible, being non-zero is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof depends on the following conjecture:

> For any matrices $V,W$, if $VW=0$ and $V\ne0$, then $W=0$.

This conjecture, unfortunately, is only true if $V$ is invertible.

Instead of showing that:

> If $\{EA,EB,EC,ED\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is linearly independent.

we will prove its contrapositive:

> If $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is linearly **dependent**, then $\{EA,EB,EC,ED\}$ is linearly **dependent**.

Suppose $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is linearly dependent. Then for some $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ (at least one of which is nonzero), we have:
$$aA+bB+cC+dD=0$$

Left multiplying each side of the equation by $E$ yields:
$$a(EA)+b(EB)+c(EC)+d(ED)=0$$
where at least one of $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ is nonzero. Thus, by definition, $\{EA,EB,EC,ED\}$ is linearly dependent, as desired.

Comment: But I was told that $\{EA,EB,EC,ED\}$ is linearly independent. I'm sorry if you started writing the answer before my fix, I got the dependence and independence totally mixed up.

Comment: Edited my answer. This should work now.